# install SQLITE with R-Tree module enabled?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, anaconda, r-tree

What is the best way of getting SQLITE's R-Tree support enabled in an Anaconda installation? Is there a repository that has this pre-compiled or an easy way of downloading the c-compiler and compiling via conda, pip, setuptools or a Python script? I'm using Windows 10 64bit.

EDIT:
I issued:

```
conda install -c conda-forge sqlite --force-reinstall
```

I tried importing sqlite and sqlite3 separately and testing for the presence of rtree with the same negative result:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("D:\\Projects\\...\\data\\working_copy\\rtree_example.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE demo_index USING rtree(
   id,              -- Integer primary key
   minX, maxX,      -- Minimum and maximum X coordinate
   minY, maxY       -- Minimum and maximum Y coordinate
)''')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 5, in 
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such module: rtree

While I'd like to fix this with simply reinstalling, I could compile SQLITE myself as described: https://sqlite.org/rtree.html and https://sqlite.org/amalgamation.html. But, I'm not sure where to put the new executable so my Python 3 geospatial libraries work properly.

Comment: What Python version are you using? It seems to work for me. I have `python 3.7.6 h0371630_2 ` from conda. I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

[The Anaconda feedstock](https://github.com/AnacondaRecipes/sqlite-feedstock/blob/fab376ca5a01afee090f485d478669245951b790/recipe/bld.bat) doesn't seem to build the extension, but [the Conda Forge one](https://github.com/conda-forge/sqlite-feedstock/blob/ba61245f9901a5e631a8db8f679fcbc27aba0be9/recipe/bld.bat) does. So, you should be able to use

```
conda install -c conda-forge sqlite
```

Comment: Thanks merv. I tried conda-forge. But still do not appear to have rtree support. I've edited my post accordingly.